# Where are the header files of the ios SDK located? and where of OSX?

Tags: ios, macos, header

I can open the header files by command-clicking in XCode - but I want to know where they are located.

I want to parse them for a project (as text files, not as header files).

I've looked all over on my disk - to find them.

For instance - where is UIViewController.h located?

Comment: When you command-click them in Xcode, just select Open in Finder to get the location of the header files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SDK headers are located in the Xcode installation.

For example:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h
```